# Can You Put an if / else Statement Inside a .on() Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Finally found some code that will change the hover color of an svg above the hover element in the DOM, but now I want to add some logic to it.

HTML

```
<div class="tag--active grid__item small--one-third medium--one-third large--one-third xlarge--one-third">                              
    <div class="tag-container">
        <a class="svg-filter-link" href="">
            <div class="top clearfix">
            <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?-->
                <svg width="41px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 41 48" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                    <!-- Generator: Sketch 39.1 (31720) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
                    <title>filter-icn-bedbug</title>
                    <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
                    <defs></defs>
                    <g id="Pest-Peeve-Web" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <g id="Shopfront" transform="translate(-402.000000, -706.000000)" fill="#C8C8C8">
                            <g id="filter-icn-pest" transform="translate(154.000000, 698.000000)">
                                <path d="M284.00492,...bunch of numbers... L277.822737,10.9244995 Z" id="filter-icn-bedbug"></path>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div class="bottom">
            <a title="Title" href="/collections/tag">Link Text</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#0BACFF'});
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#939393'});
        }
}, ".tag-container a");
```

At this point, the svg will change color like it should when hovering, then change back when not hovered.  However, the problem is that the "tag--active" icon (the active link) is already highlighted when the page loads, so after you hover over it, it removes the highlighting.

I want to add logic saying, "If it's already this color, don't do anything", but the following won't work:

```
$(document).on({
    if ($(this).closest(".grid__item").hasClass("tag--active") == 'false') {
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#0BACFF'});
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#939393'});
        }
    }
}, ".tag-container a");
```

I think I must be using the wrong syntax.  How would you do it?

Comment: I would check what context you're getting from `$(this)`. Try outputting it to `console.log()`

Comment: You are passing `on` an object with two properties representing events and their handlers. They are two separate events and so the `if` will need to be performed inside each method. You cannot have `if` statements, `while/for` loops and other such things inside an object literal, that will lead to a syntax error.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.  I have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `not()` filter instead of `if()`.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave',  ".tag-container a", function(event) {
  var fillColor = event.type === 'mouseenter' ? '#0BACFF' : '#939393';
  $(this).closest(".grid__item").not('.tag--aactive').find('svg path').css({ 'fill': fillColor });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it the way you are trying to, but you can make it this way:

```
$(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            if ($(this).closest(".grid__item").hasClass("tag--active") == 'false') {
                $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#0BACFF'});
            }
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            if ($(this).closest(".grid__item").hasClass("tag--active") == 'false') {
                $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#939393'});
            }
        }
    }
}, ".tag-container a");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this,

```
$(document).on(".tag-container a", 'mouseenter' function(){
    if ($(this).closest(".grid__item").hasClass("tag--active")) {
        $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#0BACFF'});

    }
});

$(document).on(".tag-container a", 'mouseleave' function(){
    $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#939393'});
});
```

Comment: NO need to use `true` or `false` in `.hasClass()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare statements inside a object expression, but you can declare statements inside a block, inside a body or inside a sequence expression.

When editing your code, I've not used `'if'` statement, but the `&&` operator to run a single action inside the block of each function declared in the first parameter of `$.fn.on`.

```
(document).on({

    mouseenter: function () {
        // condition
        !$(this).closest(".grid__item").hasClass("tag--active") &&
        $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#0BACFF'});
    },

    mouseleave: function () {
        // condition
        !$(this).closest(".grid__item").hasClass("tag--active") &&
        $(this).closest('.tag-container').find('svg path').css({'fill': '#939393'});
    }

}, ".tag-container a");
```